# Angular 9 with Tailwind CSS: Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(customWebpackConfig)

Tags: angular, angular9, tailwind-css

Did anyone encounter this issue? I am setting up my Angular 9 with a Tailwind CSS

````
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(customWebpackConfig).```
````